# Replace unidentified characters in xml by notepad++

Tags: regex, xml, replace, utf-8, notepad++

I need to find and replace all unidentified characters in an xml file using notepad++. I don't know the technical term to describe those unidentified characters, probably they cant even be called characters, so i'm attaching an example image:

[image: example case]

The stuff between "string" and "/string" is what i need to find. You know: they can't be copied like text because they're not actually text and if i try to copy it here it looks like this:

So how do i find all of them (excluding newlines) and clear (replace with "blank") from the file by using regex?

edit: Encoding >> Convert to UTF-8 does not clear those

edit: I uploaded a sample file to better illustrate the situation here: https://file.io/QsyodE : I need to weed out the unidentified stuff like the ones in "Genre" strings, the ones before the kanji(?) characters. You can't see those stuff if you open the file with a pure text viewer (like notepad) because they are not actually text (and that is why I need to remove them because the fact that they are not text make the original humongous XML file unimportable by iTunes); but you see them when you open it with Notepad++.

Comment: Can you examine them at http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/?

Comment: how do you mean? like i said they cant be copied

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889996/notepad-how-to-remove-all-non-ascii-characters-with-regex

Comment: no because using [^\x00-\x7F]+ also finds non-ascii characters like é or ü with which i am fine (and dont wanna replace)

Comment: Does changing the encoding on notepad++ to  UTF-8 BOM make them workable?

Comment: no that doesn't help either

Comment: Do you know where it starts? What's the lowest value after the x?

Comment: to answer this i need to find all first. anyway i dont think that is relevant, these are what you see in a non-text file, like what you see when you open an exe file with notepad++

Comment: Then play with `MM` in `[^\xMM-\x7F]+` until you find the correct value. Without more information we can't help you...

Comment: do you realize this is like saying i cant help you because you cant walk to a disabled person?

Comment: OP: Since the accented letters are ok with you, what you are asking is not easy since you will probably have to list every odd character you DON'T want in the regex, and replace it with space. But like Thomas Ayoub inferred, there are likely more than one ranges of characters that you can change to space, you just have to look at an ascii code chart or play around with the values of the ctrs to change to space. [Here's an asciitable](http://www.asciitable.com/) for you to figure out what characters you want removed.

Comment: are we sure they're characters? because they cant be copied even to the search tool of notepad++. Btw, I tried changing [^\xMM-\x7F]+ to [^\xEF-\x7F]+ for example but notepad++ says it's an invalid expression.

Comment: @CanCelik Thats because \xEF-x7F is an inverse range (EF is larger than 7F)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notepad++, How to remove all non ascii characters with regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889996/notepad-how-to-remove-all-non-ascii-characters-with-regex)

Answer (score 0):

The following will not find é or ü but does find xEF XBF xBE

```
\b[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+\b
```

Comment: no unfortunately it only found X1 of "Bell X1" and X96 of "Live at X96"