# Python: Removing non-ascii characters from CSV file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file of text SMS in `utf-8` encoding.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv', sep=',')
data.head()
```

It has output like:

```
id    city    department    sms                    category
01    khi      revenue      quk respns.                1
02    lhr      revenue      good.                      1
03    lhr      revenue      †h\0h2h\0hh\               0
04    isb      accounts     ?xœ1øiûüð÷üœç8i            0
05    isb      accounts     %â¡ã‘ã¸$ãªã±t%rã«ãÿã©â£    0
```

I want to remove all the records/rows where `sms` column has garbage values such as in record 3,4 and 5. May be they were written in a language other than English I am not so sure what happened to these records. Record 1 and 2 are okay to keep although language used in `sms` column is informal (as people normally do in text messages). What would be the convenient way to achieve that given that I have around 2 million records.

**Edit:**
I want to remove any row with non-ascii characters in `sms` column.

Comment: Can you clarify what the full requirement is, for instance are you trying to filter out stuff that is not all English? Not ascii?

Comment: I want to filter all records whose "sms" value is non-ascii.

Comment: [GSM 03.38](https://www.csoft.co.uk/support/character-sets#gsm_set) supports non-ascii characters so I'm not sure it's valid to restrict it to just ascii

Comment: @SalA. You might or might not want to keep certain non-ascii characters, but it solely depends on your use case. Ed Chum's answer retains them, my answer drops them. Carefully think and decide what it is you really need.

Comment: Additionally it's possible to support other languages too https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38

Comment: See my updated answer, this does the filtering in a single pass

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`str.isalnum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isalnum.html#pandas.Series.str.isalnum) to filter the rows that are not alphanumeric:

```
In[46]:
df[df['sms'].str.isalnum()]

Out[46]: 
   id city department          sms  category
0   1  khi    revenue  quk respns.         1
1   2  lhr    revenue        good.         1
```

**update**

if you really want to filter out any rows containing non-ascii characters then you can use a regex pattern:

```
In[72]:
df[~df['sms'].str.contains(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+')]

Out[72]: 
   id city department          sms  category
0   1  khi    revenue  quk respns.         1
1   2  lhr    revenue        good.         1
```

So the regex patter [`'[^\x00-\x7F]+'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889996/notepad-how-to-remove-all-non-ascii-characters-with-regex) here it looks for hex values in the ascii range up to 128 (7f) so it looks for characters in range 0-128 (not including 128), and we negate this using `^` so that it's looking for the presence of non-ascii anywhere in the text, we invert this mask using `~` and use this to mask the df

Comment: `str.isalnum('å')` -> `True`... I don't think OP wants _any_ non-ascii character.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ why should this not be valid given the OP's posted sample, currently they haven't stated the full requirements other than filtering garbage characters

Comment: Err... fair point. Btw your rows are skewed :p

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ [GSM 03.38](https://www.csoft.co.uk/support/character-sets#gsm_set)  supports that character, otherwise Nokia and Ericcson phones would have been useless in their native countries, also I'm using ipython QTConsole so the output just looks like that

Comment: @EdChum I have updated the question. You are implementing this on `department` column, while I want to do this based on `sms` column. Further, `str.isalnum()` returns false for punctuations `str.isalnum("test.") -> False`. I will try regex and will update.

Comment: I think your original post had the columns named differently, I'll update but I think the regex should work

Comment: regex worked just fine. Thanks a bunch!