# Putty logs contain ESC BEL

Tags: notepad++, special-characters, putty

Every time I work on a system, I log the outputs automatically and store it in a temporary location. I use putty for that.

My problem is that when i read the output file using notepad ++, I get characters like ESC BEL.

Do you guys know any solution for that ?

Comment: This is [not a programming question](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Well i know, but I just wanted to get some ideas.

Comment: That's not an excuse for posting an off-topic question.

Comment: Should i delete it for your convenience then ? :)

Answer (score 0):

this is because your logfile contains non-ascii characters and notepad++ is so kind to show them to you. I found a similar question : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889996/how-do-i-remove-all-non-ascii-characters-with-regex-and-notepad)

I have only 11 reputation so I cannot comment, so I will answer Mr 111k Reputation here: The Question is about ascii and non ascii characters and about log files and a very popular program used to code. So I think the question is not off-topic.

But the question is not new, there are some very similar Questions asked also here. Thank you for pointing out any previous asked question that is similar to this one.

Comment: Hi Max, yeah got some pretty great ideas there. Thanks mate.