# Issues with Google fonts and Sass

Tags: css, laravel, sass, google-fonts

I'm trying to learn Laravel and I've run into an issue that I can't seem to figure out with Google Fonts and Sass.

I'm trying to load my font on app.scss with:

```
// Fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap');

// Variables
@import 'variables';

// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

But it compiles to app.css as:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;
700&display=swap);@charset "UTF-8";
```

If I manually correct app.css it works. But how do I get Sass or Laravel to compile it properly?

Comment: Sass will include a @charset declaration in the CSS-output if there are any non-ASCII characters in your source files. Might be worth to check your source files.

Comment: @DanielSixl Thanks for the reply. I've looked over the app.scss and _variables files with hidden whitespace showing and I've used the vscode ext. highlight bad chars. But I can't find any non-ASCII chars. Is there a better way to check for non-ASCII Chars?

Comment: We can grep for them on Linux: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001177/how-do-i-grep-for-all-non-ascii-characters
But I like to use Notepad++ like described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889996/how-do-i-remove-all-non-ascii-characters-with-regex-and-notepad

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a known bug in Webpack which appears to be still open.

Details here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10873

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by modifying it as follows:

original:

```
@import url ("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@400;700&display=swap");
```

modified:

```
 @import url ("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:400,700");
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work. Google returns Error 400: invalid selector.

Comment: If you change the url removing "wght@" and semicolon, you have to change also "css2" into "css". In this way works.