# How to remove special characters,unicode emojis in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Good afternoon everyone, I have a problem to clear special characters in a string column of the dataframe, I just want to remove special characters like html components, emojis and unicode errors, for example `\u2013`.

does anyone have an regular expression to help me?
Or any suggestions on how to treat this problem?

input:

```
i want to remove  and codes "\u2022"
```

expected output:

```
i want to remove and codes
```

I tried:

```
re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9 \u2022]+', '', nome)

regexp_replace('nome', '\r\n|/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/u', ' ')
```

df = df.withColumn(
"value_2",
F.regexp_replace(F.regexp_replace("value", "[^\x00-\x7F]+", ""), '""', '')
)

df = df.withColumn("new",df.text.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').decode('ascii'))

tried some solutions but none recognizes the character "\u2013", has anyone experienced this?

Comment: an easy way to do this is to simply encode and then decode your string as ascii `'i want to remove ☺ and codes "\u2022"'.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').decode('ascii')`, now you just have to take care of double spaces or double `""` if you have them, but thats another simple string substitution

Answer (score 2):

You can use this [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889996/how-do-i-remove-all-non-ascii-characters-with-regex-and-notepad) to remove all unicode caracters from the column with `regexp_replace` function. Then remove extra double quotes that can remain:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([('i want to remove  and codes "\u2022"',)], ["value"])

df = df.withColumn(
    "value_2",
    F.regexp_replace(F.regexp_replace("value", "[^\x00-\x7F]+", ""), '""', '')
)

df.show(truncate=False)

#+---------------------------------+----------------------------+
#|value                            |value_2                     |
#+---------------------------------+----------------------------+
#|i want to remove  and codes "•"|i want to remove  and codes |
#+---------------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
L=re.findall(r"[^•]+", "abdasfrasdfadfsadfaa•sdf•adsfasfasfasf")
print(L) # prints ['abdasfrasdfadfs', 'adfaa', 'sdf', 'adsfasfasfasf']
```

So to remove the smiley and bullet emoji(\u2022),
You apply that pattern above, call findall method, and then join the returned list.
Like below:

```
import re
given_string = "Your input• string "
result_string = "".join(re.findall(r"[^•]+", given_string))
print(result_string) #prints 'Your input string '
```

if you know unicode number of emojis you can replace emojis with unicode number like below:

```
result_string = "".join(re.findall(r"[^\u2022]+", given_string))
```

Comment: I managed to solve the problem as follows:

result_string = re.sub('"\\\\u2022\\"'," ",given_string )

Thanks to everyone for the suggested solutions.