# remove unprintable/Unicode characters from data

Tags: notepad++

I have an `MS-Excel.csv` dataset which has unprintable or Unicode characters that appear as `xA0`, `x85`, `x92`, `x93` and `x94` (white text, black box) alongside the text/string. How can I remove/replace all these instances from the data using `Notepad++`?

Comment: Seems like you are looking to remove "ASCII control characters (0 to 31)". Maybe this can help ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28001656/4168707

Comment: Please read: [How to find and replace unrecognizable characters in multiple files of a folder with the correct character using Notepad ++?](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/21134/how-to-find-and-replace-unrecognizable-characters-in-multiple-files-of-a-folder-with-the-correct-character-using-notepad)